# Can an app have dependency on another add-on - Appsource app

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, appsource

I am planning to put an app on appsource that will be an extension for **dynamics 365 for customer service**. my app will require the use of **customer self service portal**. Hence we will be doing customization on the the customer self service portal(like adding new pages). We will then package the solution for submission.

I read app review guidelines which says "**Your app must be easy and quick to configure and setup (no customization required).**".

Does Microsoft allows publishing of apps that depend on another add-on(like customer self service portal) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A published app that is dependent on another app must list the app dependency. Take a look at the syntax on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-json-files